# SQL CODE is not working On my Delete link i have set my SQL correctly

Tags: php, sql, web

So this is my delete link

```
<?php                       
    while ($res = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
<tr>
         <td><?php echo $res['ENo']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $res['Lastname']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $res['Firstname']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $res['MI']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $res['Address']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $res['Gender']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $res['MobileNo']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $res['Position']; ?></td>
         <td>
            <a href="function.php?delete=<?php echo $res['ENo']; ?>" class="danger">Delete</a>
         </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and this is my SQL query

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $id = $_GET['delete'];

    $d = $mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM `tbllist` WHERE ENo = $id") or die($mysqli->error());

    if($d){
    header("location:index.php");
    }
}
```

it seems ok in code but its not deleting the data in the database please help its my project for my programming subject in school

Comment: Do you have `$db` variable declared with proper value in your `functions.php` file?

Comment: Did you try executing the same query directly and check if it works? 
Were there any error messages?
One more thing to check is if the DB user has the right permissions.

Comment: @DawidGalecki Yes sir, actually i have save button that is currently working fine

Comment: @ItzikGili directly, you mean i put the id number on the `$d = $mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM tbllist WHERE ENo = $id")` i tried that but its not working too

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? "Not working" is pretty broad. Additionally, be warned that this code is widely open for SQL injections

Comment: @Nico Hasse , well it is just for a simple crud project in school, anyway i cant seem to figure out where to start debugging , because im not that good in sql

though it shows this after i click Delete link `http://localhost/function.php?delete=2`

the 2 in the delete=2 is the id number of the data i tried to delete

Comment: No, it means using any other client to connect to your DB and try running the same query (without the variable of course) and the same user. This would be a good approach to start debugging.

Comment: .....you should really start debugging. For example, why is there a `$` in front of a method call? Is `$mysqli_query` a closure you've developed? Or is this a typo and you wanted to write `$mysqli->query`?

Comment: @NicoHaase actually i just copied `$mysqli_query` on yt but i tried to use `$mysqli->query` its still doing the same thing, nothing happened

Comment: So, **what have you tried to debug the problem**? Is that `DELETE` query even executed? Is it built correct? When you run that manually, does it work?

Comment: i just removed the ` $` in the `$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `tbllist` WHERE ENo = $id")` then it starts working fine, how weird

Comment: anyway thanks for your comments sir keep safe

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM `tbllist` WHERE ENo = $id")
```

to

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `tbllist` WHERE ENo = $id")
```

Comment: can u please share data in $mysqli variable

Comment: you mean this? `$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db);`

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of $id, is that correct?